# E/R diagram for sports league database

Tags: database-design

I am attempting to create a data model for a sports league

There are two entities in my domain. The first entity is a Manager and the second is a Team.

A Manager has

- personnel id
- first name
- last name
- birth date
- birthplace

A Team has one Manager

If these are the design constraints, then how can we connect these two constraints?

Answer (score 1):

The unique identifier for Manager would be the personnel id.  That identifier would migrate to Team as a column and thus refer back to Manager.  This will ensure each Team can be managed by one and only one Manager.  This constraint would be a Foreign Key constraint.  The constraint on Manager, which specifies the personnel id as the key, would be called a Primary Key constraint.

Answer (score 1):

@todd-everett is quite right.

But I propose a time-lined solution, as although a team is currently managed by PersonA, it has been managed by PersonB, PersonC, etc. in the past.

[image]